# Why would phpMyAdmin be working with 127.0.0.1 blocked?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Newbie with all this. My background provides familiarity with PHP as well as databases...

Setting up EC2 and have gotten as far as installing phpMyAdmin with lots of bumps and restarts (and denting that learning curve like crazy! :-) )

Everything is working but how it is working has me concerned, sort of like I may be setting up problems in the future...

The .conf file needed (phpmyadmin.com) only works if I comment out the Allow from 127.0.0.1, the only thing not commented our are the aliases

Scratching your head? I sure am...

Thoughts? Feedback?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are referring to the Apache configuration instead of the phpMyAdmin configuration. Apache will allow all hosts, unless there are any Allow statements. In that case it will only allow the hosts matched in the Allow statement.

You can set up an allow statement which allows all hosts to access phpMyAdmin.

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

You can modify the allow statement with subnets (like 1.2.3.0/24) and have multiple allow statements.

Comment: Yes, confusion abounds right now. We were following a combination of 3 sets of instructions and one was entirely incorrect -- they had mus installing everything on etc/share instead of /var/www/html... back tracking now and hoping I reverse everything in good order...